Is it possible to cudaDeviceSynchronize from cuda-gdb
I am trying to step through host code that calls several kernels during its course. I was wondering if I can set an arbitrary breakpoint in the host code and manually cudaDeviceSynchronize from cuda-gdb command line. Is this possible?
EDIT:
My usecase is that I want to inspect the values for the following two lines of code
uint32_t *resultValb4Sort = thrust::max_element(thrust::device, binningState.point_list_unsorted, binningState.point_list_unsorted + num_rendered); 
uint64_t *resultKeyb4Sort = thrust::max_element(thrust::device, binningState.point_list_keys_unsorted, binningState.point_list_keys_unsorted + num_rendered); 

However, If I directly print their values on a breakpoint directly after the two lines, it prints 0. I am considering two options why this might happen:

The kernels have not yet finished and therefore I cannot fetch the value from the pointer
If I copy them to host memory first, then I can inspect the value correctly. Can I not print device memory from host code?


Setting and hitting a breakpoint in host code does not halt device execution in any way that I am aware of.  Therefore, once you hit the breakpoint, all previously-launched kernels will "presumably" run to conclusion at that point.  There isn't any command in cuda-gdb to force-launch kernels that have not yet been launched by host code.

I guess I mention that to indicate that to me, anyway, its not clear what you hope to accomplish.  Anyway there is no way to manually force a cudaDeviceSynchronize from cuda-gdb menus/commands.

You could make kernel launches synchronous using environment variable CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING

You cannot use cuda-gdb print to access/view/print device memory, when stopped in host code.  You must be stopped in device code.

To be able to wait for a kernel to finish execution without manually adding synchronization calls, one can set the environment variable CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 . This will make all kernel launches synchronous and could help stepping through the code with cuda-gdb.
Regarding your added question:
uint32_t *resultValb4Sort = thrust::max_element(thrust::device, binningState.point_list_unsorted, binningState.point_list_unsorted + num_rendered); 
uint64_t *resultKeyb4Sort = thrust::max_element(thrust::device, binningState.point_list_keys_unsorted, binningState.point_list_keys_unsorted + num_rendered)


Here, the call to thrust::max_element(thrust::device,...) will only return after the kernels are complete (the internal implementation needs to copy the index of the maximum to the host and synchronize to be able to return a pointer to the max element).
The returned pointer points to the element in device memory, and cannot be dereferenced with cuda-gdb for printing from host code. You would need to manually copy the element to the host.


Thanks for the answer. Regarding point #3:
Is the cuda-gdb command print ((@global uint32_t *)resultValb4Sort)[0] enough to "copy device data to host" or I need to explicitly add a line to my program with cudaMemcpy and recompile?

I don't know. you could try it to see if it works.

The only way to inspect device memory in cuda-gdb is to be stopped at a breakpoint in device code.  print will not be able to do this if stopped at a breakpoint in host code.
